# Invalid HTTP response The underlying connection was closed:

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, paypal-adaptive-payments

Hi i am facing some problem in Paypal integration, i find error of this block  on debug time .

```
ReceiverList sl = new ReceiverList();
           sl.receiver.Add(rec);
           PayRequest req = new PayRequest(new RequestEnvelope("en_US"), "PAY",
                              cancelURl, "USD",
                              sl, returnURL);
           req.reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError = true;
           AdaptivePaymentsService service = new AdaptivePaymentsService();
            PayResponse resp = null;
            resp = service.Pay(req);
```

**Service.Pay(req); is throw error: Invalid HTTP response The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send**